# Problem with ListBuilder repeat data in same view flutter

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, flutter-layout

I generated a list of question in my listBuilder. I want to create one view for one list because for the moment I have my entitled with the answers but all to one view.

But i want to respond of my first question and when i click to next button, generated the same screen with the next question.

```
class _Poll extends State<PollPage> {
  List<String> choix = [];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: Text("Blackblox"),
        leading: Image.asset(
          'assets/img/logo_ineat.png',
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          height: 32,
        ),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Flexible(
              child: new Container(
                child: new FutureBuilder<List<PollQuestionsDto>>(
                    future: Poll().getPollQuestions(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        if (snapshot.data != null) {
                          return new Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Expanded(
                                child: new ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                                    return PollListViewItem(
                                      entitled: snapshot.data[index].entitled,
                                      answers: snapshot.data[index].answers,
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                      } else {
                        new Text("Loading...");
                        return new CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `FutureBuilder` fires again and again. You must avoid that the `future` parameter must run once(For example, inside `initState` as usual people recommend).

Every time you interact with any element on your screen, your `State` class will rebuild and `Poll().getPollQuestions()` will fire again.

Do something like:

```
class _Poll extends State<PollPage> {
Future future;

@override
void initState(){
  future = Poll().getPollQuestions();
  super.initState();
}
```

and change `future` parameter inside `FutureBuilder`:

```
future: future,
```

Comment: thank you really ! If i want now my next list in my future, how i do ? @Esen

Comment: @MayuriXx I could'nt understand well what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: ok excuse me. Thanks to your help. I have the first element to my list of question with the possibilities answer. When i clik on my button, i have again my first element. Before that, I have all questions with the differents answers on one screen. Now, i want to generate one screen like now and when i click on my next button, i have my next question @Esen

Comment: @MayuriXx but you have List already. Next question should be inside that list or are you gonna fetch yet another List? May be you can open another question with other related code because it's really hard to resolve the problem with this perspecive :)

Answer (score 1):

```
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  Poll().getPollQuestions();
}
```